# can I do fast set difference with floats using numpy if elements are equal up to some tolerance

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point-precision, set-difference

I have two lists of float numbers, and I want to calculate the set difference between them.

With numpy I originally wrote the following code:

```
aprows = allpoints.view([('',allpoints.dtype)]*allpoints.shape[1])
rprows = toberemovedpoints.view([('',toberemovedpoints.dtype)]*toberemovedpoints.shape[1])
diff = setdiff1d(aprows, rprows).view(allpoints.dtype).reshape(-1, 2)
```

This works well for things like integers. In case of 2d points with float coordinates that are the result of some geometrical calculations, there's a problem of finite precision and rounding errors causing the set difference to miss some equalities. For now I resorted to the much, much slower:

```
diff = []
for a in allpoints: 
    remove = False
    for p in toberemovedpoints:
        if norm(p-a) < 0.1:
            remove = True
    if not remove:
        diff.append(a)
return array(diff)
```

But is there a way to write this with numpy and gain back the speed?

Note that I want the remaining points to still have their full precision, so first rounding the numbers and then do a set difference probably is not the way forward (or is it? :) )

***Edited to add an solution based on scipy.KDTree that seems to work:***

```
def remove_points_fast(allpoints, toberemovedpoints):
    diff = []
    removed = 0
    # prepare a KDTree
    from scipy.spatial import KDTree
    tree = KDTree(toberemovedpoints,  leafsize=allpoints.shape[0]+1)
    for p in allpoints:
        distance, ndx = tree.query([p], k=1)
        if distance < 0.1:
            removed += 1
        else:
            diff.append(p)
    return array(diff), removed
```

Comment: `from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree` is a much faster cython KDtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with the matrix form, you have a lot of memory consumption with larger arrays. If that does not matter, then you get the difference matrix by:

```
diff_array = allpoints[:,None] - toberemovedpoints[None,:]
```

The resulting array has as many rows as there are points in allpoints, and as many columns as there are points in toberemovedpoints. Then you can manipulate this any way you want (e.g. calculate the absolute value), which gives you a boolean array. To find which rows have any hits (absolute difference < .1), use `numpy.any`:

```
hits = numpy.any(numpy.abs(diff_array) < .1, axis=1)
```

Now you have a vector which has the same number of items as there were rows in the difference array. You can use that vector to index all points (negation because we wanted the non-matching points):

```
return allpoints[-hits]
```

This is a numpyish way of doing this. But, as I said above, it takes a lot of memory.

---

If you have larger data, then you are better off doing it point by point. Something like this:

```
return allpoints[-numpy.array([numpy.any(numpy.abs(a-toberemoved) < .1) for a in allpoints ])]
```

This should perform well in most cases, and the memory use is much lower than with the matrix solution. (For stylistic reasons you may want to use numpy.all instead of numpy.any and turn the comparison around to get rid of the negation.)

(Beware, there may be pritning mistakes in the code.)

Comment: Thank you for your solution @DrV I need to investigate why it caused some trouble in my code (but I'm pretty certain the error would be on my side, as your solution looks quite elegant).

Comment: I have the tendency of making printing mistakes and stupid thinking mistakes. Split it into small bits and use trivial numeric examples to iron out the wrinkles. I corrected one on the last line (added the conversion to an array). If you have any further problems with my code, let me know.

Comment: I really seem to have that tendency this night. Now the code has been tested, as well :)

Comment: If memory is an issue with `diff_array`, how about filtering out the obvious failures first.  For example, scale the values to integers, do `setdiff1d` in 1 dimension.  Repeat on the 2nd with values that pass.  Then do `diff_array` on what's left.